# How to show Camera Preview in metro app using javascript

Tags: microsoft-metro

i have  [**StartPreviewAsync**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.startpreviewasync) api to show camera preview on screen in C#

but not available in javascript ,so how can i get same preview(output) in javascript template??

or is any way to deploy xaml on javascript??

Answer (score 0):

WinJS seems to have a different API for handling Camera Previews. I'd take a look at [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622) example on MSDN for more details. Namely, in BasicCapture.js, we see the following function, startPreview:

```
function startPreview() { 
    displayStatus("Starting preview"); 
    id("btnStartPreview" + scenarioId).disabled = true; 
    var video = id("previewVideo" + scenarioId); 
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaCaptureMgr, { oneTimeOnly: true }); 
    video.play(); 
    displayStatus("Preview started"); 
    getCameraSettings(); 
    // Initialize sliders. 
    for (var i = 0; i < cameraControlSliders.length; i++) { 
        cameraControlSliders[i].slider.disabled = false; 
        initSlider(cameraControlSliders[i]); 
    } 
}
```

To answer your second question, the only way to load Javascript into a XAML application would be through the WebView control, and even that would not be allowed to directly control the different controls of the XAML UI. If you want to do XAML, you have to stick to C#, VB, or C++.